# How do I set up a listener to a switch in my Custom listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I want to set up a separate listener to each switch in each of my items in a listview. How do I go about accomplishing this ?

The method that is called in my asynchronous task is setQueues :

```
    private void setQueues(final JSONObject[] qInfo) 
{
    queues = new QueueItem[qInfo.length]; // QueueItem consists of a string(label) and a boolean(value)

    for(int i = 0; i < qInfo.length; i++)
    {
        queues[i] = new QueueItem();
        //final int ii = i;

        // Formatting the queue title
        String name = qInfo[i].optString("name").replace("-", " ");
        name = name.replace("_", " ");
        name = name.replace("ipinion", "");
        name = name.replace("  ", " ");
        name = capitalizeFirstLetters(name);
        queues[i].label = name;

        try {
            if(qInfo[i].getString("active").contains("1"))
            {
                Log.d("QBox", "Queue: Checkbox " + i + " : Checked TRUE");
                queues[i].value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("QBox", "Queue Checkbox " + i + " : Checked FALSE");  
                queues[i].value = false;
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    lv.setAdapter(new QueueAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.layout.queues_items, queues));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I feel like im missing something very obvious.

**Edit : The getView method from QueueAdapter :**

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    QueueHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new QueueHolder();
        holder.queueswitch = (Switch)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_switch);
        holder.txtLabel = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_text);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
    holder = (QueueHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    QueueItem queue = data[position];
    holder.txtLabel.setText(queue.label);
    holder.queueswitch.setChecked(queue.value);
    // Is this where you would set up your listener?    

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    QueueHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new QueueHolder();
        holder.queueswitch = (Switch)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_switch);
        /* TRY PUTTING IT HERE */
        holder.txtLabel = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_text);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
    holder = (QueueHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    QueueItem queue = data[position];
    holder.txtLabel.setText(queue.label);
    holder.queueswitch.setChecked(queue.value);
    holder.queueswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //DO SOMETHING
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

This way it would work! I am not sure but try putting it where "/* TRY PUTTING IT HERE */" stands, I'm not sure if it would work but it would be better since the initiating of the onClickListener only happens once...

Comment: Would it be possible to execute an AsyncTask from "here" ?

Comment: For once. The progressbar that I want to show while the task is being performed needs a context. getActivity() does not work here since QueueAdapter extends ArrayAdapter.

Comment: If your adapter is in a separate file, put an activity or context in the constructor of your adapter... If they are in the same file you can use this: 'MyActivityName.this' as activity in your Adapter